# Why doesn't Gaussian Blur work?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I did Add->Effect Strip->Gaussian Blur to a video, but nothing changed.
[image]

I looked up [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/sequencer/strips/effects/blur.html), and it did not explain much. Also, how can I have two videos: one for before effect and one for after effect, like the documentation screenshot below? My screenshot above is just splitting the preview into two, and I cannot see any difference in the panel settings (they both show "Preview") in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: your gaussian blur is doing nothing because you have to set size X and Y to some value and not let it at 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have explained why gaussian is not working in comments and it is simple as you just nned to set size X and Y to some value, but for that part "**Also, how can I have two videos: one for before effect and one for after effect, like the documentation screenshot below?**"

Just use this settings in one of your previews, you need to select channel that is shown, if your video is channel 2 and effect channel 3, just use it as I did

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Look at the right side of your screenshot where it says **Effect Stip**. Size X, Y is the size of the blur. You need to increase the value to something higher for the blur to take effect.